# ng-repeat on custom directive creating issues

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, angular-directive

I'm using directives for creating reusable components. I'm also using angular material grid component. For grid I created a custom directive called `my-grid` and for the tile I created another custom directive called `my-grid-tile`.

Below is the template function of the `myGrid` directive.

```
template: '<md-grid-list>\
             <my-grid-tile ng-repeat="tile in model.tiles | orderBy: 'tile.order'"'\
          </md-grid-list>'
```

Below is the template function of `myGridTile` directive.

```
template: '<md-grid-tile>Tile...</md-grid-tile>'
```

In the initial time everything renders fine. But when the tiles collection changes then the custom directives are rendered as it is and they are not getting compiled. Any suggestion how to solve the issue?

Comment: <my-grid-tile ng-repeat="tile in model.tiles | orderBy: 'tile.order'" '\ 
What is that ' at the end of tile.order? Probably, the error is there. try to remove it

Comment: Sorry it's a pseudo code. That typo is not there in the real code. Unfortunately the real code is little complex and heavy difficult to strip and paste here.